# A story about a demon who has to steal a jewel to free his sister

Tags: story-identification, magical-items

I read it originally with kindle (amazon book). It is a book about two main characters, one female and the other a male - I believe it is a young adult book, Sci-Fi, paranormal, romance and magic.

So on with the details:

The male, I am fairly certain, is some kind of demon who has "pet" like dragon and was paired with him at birth I think more like a familiar/pet. So he has to steal a jewel to free his sister.

There is like a demon realm and the human realm and in the human realm there are "safe heavens". They are managed by Sorcerers? I think and the jewel he has to steal is highly coveted and being held in one of these safe heavens in a vault until this magic counsel decides what to do with it. So he goes there with his friend whom I believe is a incubus or succubus?

This safe heaven in specific is run by one man that has a twin brother and a daughter - anyways basically the jewel was to be stored in a protected room in the safe heaven but her father who runs it gave it to her in secret - the little pet of the demon guy steals it from her and takes it back to his owner the demon guy.... It's actually rather funny how it happens because she's chasing the thing down the hall and to this guys room.

He gives her a fake one (unbeknownst to her) - there is an explosion downstairs where the vault is, she runs down there and believes her father is injured, they (her, the demon guy with the pet dragon and the succubus) all get attacked by another demon and they have to run for their lives..

Eventually they cross realms because they are being hunted for this jewel/stone...

If this rings a bell with anyone I really want to find the book series I think there are 3-4 books in the series?

Comment: Hmm... since the comment seems to have been deleted, you can accept your own answer 48 hours after asking the question by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons. We would very much like for you to do so. :) If you hang around the site, that will make it all the more easy. You should have enough rep to vote up and make comments now.

Answer (score 6):

I found it. It's [Chase the Dark](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/34727443-chase-the-dark)  (Steel & Stone #1) by Annette Marie

> Piper Griffiths wants one thing in life: To become a Consul, a keeper of the peace between humans and daemons. There are three obstacles in her way.
>
> The first is Lyre. Incubus. Hotter than hell and with a wicked streak to match. His greatest mission in life is to get Piper into bed and otherwise annoy the crap out of her. The second is Ash. Draconian. Powerful. Dangerous. He knows too much and reveals nothing. Also, disturbingly attractive — and scary. Did she mention scary?
>
> The third is the Sahar Stone. Top secret magical weapon of mass destruction. Previously hidden in her Consulate until thieves broke in, went on a murder spree, and disappeared with the weapon.
>
> And they left Piper to take the fall for their crimes.
>
> Now she’s on the run, her dreams of becoming a Consul shattered and every daemon in the city gunning to kill her. She’s dead on her own, but there’s no one she can trust — no one except two entirely untrustworthy daemons ... See problems one and two.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This makes me think of *The Amulet of Samarkand*, the first book in Jonathan Stroud's Bartimaeus series.

In it, a young boy is taught how to do magic - which is by summoning, binding and controlling demons. Behind the back of his master, he summons and binds a particularly powerful demon - Bartimaeus - and together they steal an amulet and defeat a powerful demon in the process. [From Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bartimaeus_Sequence#The_Amulet_of_Samarkand):

> The first book in the series, published 2003, introduces Nathaniel as the gifted 12-year-old apprentice of a middle-aged mid-level magician, Arthur Underwood. He assumes his magician name, John Mandrake, to protect him from rivals who would wish to harm him. When the magician Simon Lovelace cruelly humiliates Nathaniel in public, Nathaniel decides to take revenge by stealing Lovelace's most powerful possession, the Amulet of Samarkand. The Amulet makes the wearer invulnerable to magical (but not physical) attack. Unknown to his tutor, he begins the study of advanced magic in order to summon the djinni Bartimaeus and enslave him. Bartimaeus soon overhears Nathaniel's birth-name, which greatly reduces Nathaniel's control over him, because demons can then cast counterspells. Things soon get out of hand and Bartimaeus and Nathaniel find themselves caught in the middle of magical espionage, murder, blackmail, and revolt. Together, the two of them defeat Lovelace and his most powerful demon, Ramuthra, who was last seen destroying an entire nation. These actions ended an uneasy truce between the young magician and Bartimaeus, resulting in the demon returning to whence he came. Nathaniel and Bartimaeus are stuck in a terrifying flood of revenge and murder.

Comment: no, it's more about the girl in the first book she is 16-18 years old a witch/sorceress kind of in training to be a guardian i think at the safe heaven? This is a test by her father with the jewel/stone. The guy is a demon of some type and they (these demons) are paired with a little dragon like pet not long after birth. Thank you though for trying :)

Comment: @DanielleCody-Whitaker Yeah, couldn't really fit in the girl, but thought it was my spotty memory - it's been some time since I read Bartimaeus.